# iPad UISplitView question for Universal App

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am attempting to turn an iPhone app into a Universal App with a simple UISplitView for the iPad. I have added the following to the App Delegate:

```
> if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() ==
> UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
>         [window addSubview:splitViewController.view]; 
>         [window makeKeyAndVisible];
>     } else {
>         [window addSubview:tabBarController.view]; 
>         [window makeKeyAndVisible];
>     }
```

However, it doesn't give me the option in IB to add a UISplitViewController in the MainWindow.nib.  So, after creating a new nib and adding the App Delegate object, I linked up a SplitViewController with the splitView that I declared in the App delegate - however when I try to run it on the iPad simulator, it is still showing up as an iPhone App running on an iPad.  (@ 1/2 size)  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with your Project/Build settings rather than code at this point.

Select your Target, choose `Get Info` and make sure your `Targeted Device Family` is set to `iPad/iPhone` on all your build configurations, then do a clean build and try again.